# If user is not logged in, dont try to attempt to get the user react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So, this may seem like a very simple question. And I have researched with Stackoverflow to see is someone has the same kind of question. I could not find any.

I am using `React`, and a `NodeJS` backend. Using redux, I want to ensure that on every page load that it checks to see if the user is logged in. I am doing this:

```
`useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);`
```

the load user in Redux is:

```
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/auth/me');
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

So every time the application loads it loads the user into state.

When the user is not logged in however, I get an message in the console:
[image: Like this]

I know why I am getting the error, the route in Nodejs is protected.

Obviously, I don't want the user to see this when the page is deployed. How would I handle this error properly?

Comment: where does the user see the error?

Comment: This is located in the console of the webbrowser. I am worried about securty, the route is protected in my API but I would prefer that they dont see the api route trying to fetched.

Comment: Understood. I suggest you put a function named check auth at the top of your application and keep it on this redux. If the user is not logged in, you cannot run functions such as loadUser. And since this error message comes from the browser, I guess there's no way to block it.

Comment: so in my state I have a isAuthenticated <-- that is either true or false. so I could add that in and use an if statement `if(!iisAutenticated){run code} else{dont run}` is that possible to use in the useEffect?

Comment: Absolutely. You can even keep the loading state on a state at first and pull it back to a completed state after this check. Meanwhile, you can show a loading spinner.

Comment: If the user requests a protected route without being logged in your backend could redirect to the login route. Then inside your login component don't do this fetch.

Comment: @trixn I thought about this also. However, the login page is React, not nodejs.

Comment: @ShaunStone Why is that a problem? You will have two routes in your backend. One is protected and serves your app and one is the login route that is not protected and also serves your app. The difference is that the first route redirects to the login route if the user is not authenticated. Of course your app then should render the login form if the route is the login route.

Comment: @trixn Oh! after rereading I get what you saying. Redirect to the login Route thats inside the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use local storage api. So, when someone logs in you should generate some kind of auth token and save it in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("token",TOKEN_VALUE)
```

then in your react app check if this value exist or not using:

```
localStorage.getItem("token")
```

if it exists then the user is still logged in and otherwise if not

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

This also will achieve a great user experience as they won't need to sign in everytime and they won't be logged out unless they want

Comment: So I have a cookie that is saved in localstorage with jwt. Should I also store a token in localstorage? or can I use the cookie in this same way? The problem is, you need to use the API to verify the cookie.. right?

Comment: How do you go about invalidating that token? Also that solution is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Every script on your page can read the local storage and possibly steal the tokens of all your users.

Comment: @trixn I appreciate you working with me. In my backend I have authentication that each of my protect routes go through to ensure that the cookie is valid. the cookie, when the user logged in, is stored in the cookie area inside the browser local storage. Is this vulerable? How would you do it? headers with jwt tokens have the same vulberabity no?

Comment: @ShaunStone Cookies are stored in an http only area and can't be read by scripts so they are safe. If you already have a session management solution in place (most likely a db session table ?) there is no need to create an unsafe solution on top of it. You have an endpoint serving your react app, right? Create another one that is unprotected that only matches your login route. Your react app should render the login form when mounting on that route. If an unauthenticated user requests any other route other than the login route -> redirect to the login route.

Comment: @trixn well crap - I dont have a session table. How I was doing it is that on every page load it would verify the token cookie, Hence the error when the user is not logged in. do you have any documentation on user sessions? that might be the way to go. Instead of calling the loaduser() function on every pageload.

Comment: @ShaunStone Okay so you can still use JWT authentication but don't store it in local storage. Credentials should always be stored as cookies. But then it is the same procedure. Does your react app use any kind of routing, like `react-router`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217140/discussion-between-trixn-and-shaun-stone).

Comment: @trixn Yes, and I have protected Routes. and I use Redux to load the user into state with an isAuthenticated <-- boolean to verify if they are logged in. So if the cookie is stored in localstorage during login, they the boolean is true. and then it checks to see if this cookie (and verified with backend) is still in localstorage to verify user permissions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible cases to consider:

1. The user directly navigates to a protected url while not being authenticated. In this case your backend knows the api requests it will try to make will fail when your react app renders the content of that route. Instead it should redirect (`302 Found`) to the login route (which will let your react app render the login form instead of the original page he requested) where no api requests are made that require authentication.
2. The user hits an api endpoint without being authenticated. In that case your backend should respond with `401 Unauthorized`. Your react app should catch that and render the login form.

You should always assume that the user might perform an unauthorized request at any time and gracefully handle that.

So what you need to handle both cases is:

1. Two routes that serve your app. One is the login route that just serves your app. The other one is also just serving the app but only if the user is authenticated. Otherwise it should redirect to the login route. I'm assuming that your react app will only render the login form when first mounting on the login route where no api request happen that require authentication.
2. A handler in your react app that re-directs to/renders your login form in case an API request failed with `401`.